# Calculating group value depending on column value group delimiter

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Having simple data source (`[ID]` and `[Value]`) I need to calculate third column called `[Group]` like this:

[image]

The rules are simple:

1. The `~` sign match the start of new group
2. The data is never staring or ending with `~` sign (I am not going to have `~` value for `[ID] = 1` or `MAX([ID]) = 1`)
3. I do not care about the group value of the `~` sign (it can be null, empty string, number, etc.)

I want to calculated the `[Group]` column value in a simple select, but was not able to do this using `LAG` function. I am wondering is there any clever way to do this?

Here is the a sample data:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] TINYINT
   ,[Value] CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [Value])
VALUES   (1,'A')
        ,(2,'A')
        ,(3,'A')
        ,(4,'~')
        ,(5,'A')
        ,(6,'A')
        ,(7,'A')
        ,(8,'~')
        ,(9,'A')
        ,(10,'A')
        ,(11,'~')
        ,(12,'A');

SELECT [ID]
      ,[Value]
FROM @DataSource;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems trivial enough, using [`OVER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) and the `ROWS` window specifier:

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[Value]
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Value = '~' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
           (ORDER BY ID
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
       + 1 as [Group]
FROM @DataSource;
```

Result:

```
ID   Value Group
---- ----- -----------
1    A     1
2    A     1
3    A     1
4    ~     2
5    A     2
6    A     2
7    A     2
8    ~     3
9    A     3
10   A     3
11   ~     4
12   A     4
```

The logic, of course, being that a group number can be determined purely by asking the question "how many `~`s occur before this particular row?" - which would produce a 0-based group number so I'm also adding one to it. The flexibility of the OP in not caring what value is assigned for `~` rows meant no special casing logic was required.